# ASP/SQL Server Express: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

Windows 7, IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2008 R2, ASP classic (website I want to upgrade, but need to make it works).

connection string:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10; Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=shoshvi_sql-db;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout =1
```

I am getting this annoying error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0  '80004005'
>
> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
>
> filename.asp, line 15

What I tried, as I remember:

- Test connection using SSMS (works, to localhost and to other server in LAN)
- Test connection using SQLCMD (works, to localhost and to other server in LAN)
- Tried  many datasources/servers ( `name\SQLExpress`, `.\SQLExpress`, .\SQLEXPRESS)
- Tried to change settings in Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2008\Configuration Tools, enable TCP/IP, Named Pipes, look all sub items and find wrong configuration.
  after any change, I was restarted service.
- Tried to enable SQL Server Browser.
- Tried to connect to other SQL Server in the same network, using SA and SA password (in the other "server" I could use IIS/ASP/MSSQL and works fine).
- Tried to disable Windows Firewall
- Tried to enable remote connections to SQL Server Express
- Tried  Integrated Security=SSPI
- Tried Windows Administrator password
- Tried change to TCP/IP (and get other error, same reason)
- Tried to search google, and stackOverflow and other for an idea.
- Tried similar questions here.

What more?

Thanks !

Comment: did you try creating a sqllogin and password and use that instead of SSPI

Comment: yes, and also tried use SA and  Windows Administrator account.

Comment: You are intending to use the sqlexpress instance or is the db in the sqlserver instance?

Comment: sqlexpress, the DB was attached with SSMS

Comment: Why do you have such a short connection timeout?

Comment: To get the "not connected" error fast. For localhost I think it's need to work.

Comment: Did you try the localhost versions - `Data Source=127.0.0.1`, `Data Source=(local)`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. And make sure you have TCP/IP enabled under 'SQL Native Client Configuration' on SQL Configuration Manager.

```
PROVIDER=SQLNCLI;DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=shoshvi_sql-db;UID=username;PWD=password;
```

Comment: Your solution is half way. After a deep find I was need to enable IP Addresses, not the TCP/IP protocol only.
Still not know why Shared Memory not works....

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that any ALIAS you're using is created properly.

I was encountering exactly the same error and it turned out to be that I hadn't created the alias used in a script when trying to run it on a new machine.